# How can I wrap this PowerShell cmdlet into a timeout function?

Tags: multithreading, powershell, asynchronous, delegates, task

I've tried (and failed) to get `[System.Delegate]::CreateDelegate()` to work, and `New-Object [System.Threading.Tasks.Task]::Run()` to work. [Start-Job](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/start-job) with [Wait-Job](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/wait-job). PowerShell does not seem to be setup to do an asynchronous task with a wait timeout. Why?

```
do
{
    Sleep 2;
    $testShare = Test-Path "\\$server\c$";
    Write-Host "Share availability is:" $testShare;
}while($testShare -eq $true) # wait for the share to become unavailable
```

Adam's suggestion

```
do
{
    Sleep 1;
    #$testShare = Test-Path "\\$server\c$"; # could use code here to deal with the hanging

    $timeout_in_seconds = 5;
    $timer = [Diagnostics.Stopwatch]::StartNew();
    do
    {
        Write-Host "    Test-path inside of second do loop";
        Start-Sleep -Seconds 1;
        $testShare = Test-Path "\\$server\c$";
        Write-Host "    (Inner loop) Share availability is:" $testShare;
    } while ( (1 -eq 1) -and ($timer.Elapsed.TotalSeconds -lt $timeout_in_seconds) )
    $timer.Stop();
    $timer.Elapsed.TotalSeconds;

    Write-Host "";
    Write-Host "(Outer loop) Share availability is:" $testShare;
} while($testShare -eq $true) # wait for the share to become unavailable
```

#### Output

```
    Test-path inside of second do loop
    (Inner loop) Share availability is: True
    Test-path inside of second do loop
    (Inner loop) Share availability is: True
    Test-path inside of second do loop
    (Inner loop) Share availability is: True
    Test-path inside of second do loop
    (Inner loop) Share availability is: True
    Test-path inside of second do loop
    (Inner loop) Share availability is: True
5.3015436

(Outer loop) Share availability is: True
    Test-path inside of second do loop
    (Inner loop) Share availability is: True
    Test-path inside of second do loop
    (Inner loop) Share availability is: True
    Test-path inside of second do loop
    (Inner loop) Share availability is: True
    Test-path inside of second do loop
    (Inner loop) Share availability is: True
    Test-path inside of second do loop
    (Inner loop) Share availability is: True
5.2303907

(Outer loop) Share availability is: True
    Test-path inside of second do loop
    (Inner loop) Share availability is: True
    Test-path inside of second do loop
    (Inner loop) Share availability is: False
**42.1773323**

(Outer loop) Share availability is: False
Ping availability is: False
```

Comment: In your code block, don't you mean `$testShare -eq $false`? According to the comment, you want the loop to wait until the share gets available

Comment: your `do/while` is the wrong construct to use with `$testShare -eq $true`. it will run ONCE and then exit if the path is NOT found. if you want to wait until the path is found ... use `do/until`. [*grin*]

Comment: @Bbb The question is quite unclear. What is exact issue you have? Waiting asynchronously for a share availability with a timeout?

Comment: The `$testShare -eq $true` makes sense. The call to `Test-Path` would return true when the path is there. As long as that is true, the loop continues. She\He wants it to be true because they're waiting for the share to become unavailable at which point the `Test-Path` call returns false. It looks like they're running this to determine when a share un-mounts.

Comment: Yes that is correct Adam. I want to see when the share is no longer available (for more detail, later on in the code I wait until ping fails and then I move on test when RDP is available)

Answer (score 2):

A couple of things...

Having a timeout doesn't necessitate asynchronous processing. You could have a synchronous process (like your example) that has a timeout.

A simple synchronous script with a timeout...

```
$timeout_in_seconds = 10
$timer = [Diagnostics.Stopwatch]::StartNew()

do {
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 1
    Write-Host 'Doing stuff'

} while ( (1 -eq 1) -and ($timer.Elapsed.TotalSeconds -lt $timeout_in_seconds) )

$timer.Stop()
$timer.Elapsed.TotalSeconds
```

I simplified your example just a hair to demonstrate the point. I'm setting a run interval (10 seconds). I'm firing up a timer. I run a loop until I've hit a success condition (which, in this example, I never will) or I hit the timeout. You'd do the same thing.

For your specific example, consider something like...

```
$server = '...'
$timeout_in_seconds = 5;
$timer = [Diagnostics.Stopwatch]::StartNew();

do {
    Write-Host "Test-path inside of loop";
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 1;
    $testShare = Test-Path "\\$server\c$";
    Write-Host "Share availability is:" $testShare;
} while ( $($testShare) -and ($timer.Elapsed.TotalSeconds -lt $timeout_in_seconds) )

$timer.Stop();
$timer.Elapsed.TotalSeconds;
```

The loop terminates once the share exists or the time interval is reached. Note, you'll need to set your `$server` variable.

Comment: Hi Adam, if I implemented your suggestion properly, your example brings me to the same situation. I've added the code to match what you were saying up top and also will show what the output looks like. I still think there needs to be a worker thread (or equivalent) and something that monitors it and kills it if it exceeds a preset time limit and trying to implement that is what I'm after.

Comment: Then I apologize. I didn’t understand your question. What’s the behavior you want to see? I was expounding on the code in your example, which has no timeout functionality.

Comment: I posted my interpretation of your suggestion and the results with the timer output, let me know what you think. Your reply skills outmatched my slow edit skills :) but it should be updated in the original question now.

Comment: Hi Adam, any other ideas after seeing the time difference (if you see in the code, it times out at about 42 seconds, which is too long to wait) when it cannot reach the path.

Comment: Updated my answer. Let me know if that helped.