# Test-Path timeout for PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to routinely check the presence of particular strings in text files on hundreds of computers on our domain.

```
foreach ($computer in $computers) {
    $hostname = $computer.DNSHostName
    if (Test-Connection $hostname -Count 2 -Quiet) {
        $FilePath = "\\" + $hostname + "c$\SomeDirectory\SomeFile.txt"
        if (Test-Path -Path $FilePath) {
            # Check for string
        }
    }
}
```

For the most part, the pattern of [Test-Connection](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/test-connection) and then [Test-Path](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/test-path) is effective and fast. There are certain computers, however, that ping successfully, but `Test-Path` takes around 60 seconds to resolve to `FALSE`. I'm not sure why, but it may be a domain trust issue.

For situations like this, I would like to have a timeout for `Test-Path` that defaults to `FALSE` if it takes more than two seconds.

Unfortunately, the solution in a related question ([How can I wrap this PowerShell cmdlet into a timeout function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56087602/how-can-i-wrap-this-powershell-cmdlet-into-a-timeout-function)) does not apply to my situation. The proposed do-while loop gets hung up in the code block.

I've been experimenting with Jobs, but it appears even this won't force quit the `Test-Path` command:

```
Start-Job -ScriptBlock {param($Path) Test-Path $Path} -ArgumentList $Path | Wait-Job -Timeout 2 | Remove-Job -Force
```

The job continues to hang in the background. Is this the cleanest way I can achieve my requirements above? Is there a better way to timeout Test-Path so the script doesn't hang besides spawning asynchronous activities?

Comment: This is a Windows File Sharing issue and could require monkeying with Windows Registry settings to decrease the timeout which I do not recommend. The best solution is to figure out and solve the timeout/permission issue. A related question might provide some help: https://superuser.com/q/453741/778550

Comment: Another option is to run the foreach block in parallel `ForEach -Parallel`. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/psworkflow/about/about_foreach-parallel?view=powershell-5.1

Comment: Aren't you missing a backslash after the $hostname and before the `C$` ?

Answer (score 7):

Wrap your code in a `[powershell]` object and call `BeginInvoke()` to execute it asynchronously, then use the associated WaitHandle to wait for it to complete only for a set amount of time.

```
$sleepDuration = Get-Random 2,3
$ps = [powershell]::Create().AddScript("Start-Sleep -Seconds $sleepDuration; 'Done!'")

# execute it asynchronously
$handle = $ps.BeginInvoke()

# Wait 2500 milliseconds for it to finish
if(-not $handle.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne(2500)){
    throw "timed out"
    return
}

# WaitOne() returned $true, let's fetch the result
$result = $ps.EndInvoke($handle)

return $result
```

In the example above, we randomly sleep for either 2 or 3 seconds, but set a 2 and a half second timeout - try running it a couple of times to see the effect :)